# Record not inserted after interceptor onSave()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor, spring-transactions

my app consists of spring @transaction with hibernate. I am trying to use hibernate interceptor.  i registered the interceptor as

```
getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().withOptions().interceptor(interceptor).openSession();
```

And the actual interceptor extends EmptyInterceptor and i am overriding onSave() method.

the problem is that the interceptor onSave() method is called but after that , the actual entity does not get inserted in the database.

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    System.out.println("inside interceptor - on save");
    {
        // my changes here . setting a field of the entity.

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Interceptor.onSave()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onSave(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[])):

> Called **before** an object is saved. The interceptor may modify the state, which will be used for the SQL INSERT and propagated to the persistent object.

So the changes are commited to the persistent object and the `INSERT` statement that Hibernate will issue to the database.

You might want to make sure you are searching for the record once the `@Transactional` method has finished, if you're querying the database with a different session than the one that opened the transaction. That is when Spring will commit the transaction to the database.

You could also try using [Interceptor.afterTransactionCompletion()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#afterTransactionCompletion(org.hibernate.Transaction)) to check if the record is effectvely inserted.

> Called after a transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: thank you, yes I modify the state of the persistent object but the insert query never gets fired even after transaction is completed

Answer (score 0):

You need to call super.onSave() at the end of your method above. Your override allows you to make changes to the object, add logging, etc. but it needs the base method to actually perform the SQL operation.